# ERROR : TiExceptionHandler: Message: Uncaught Error: Index 4 requested, with a size of 4

Tags: java, android, sql, appcelerator

I am trying to change the content displayed depending on the image selected. The code is:

```
Ti.Database.install('data.sqlite', 'datadb');
var db = Titanium.Database.open('datadb');
var data = db.execute('select * from data');
var imageBook = [];


while(data.isValidRow()){       

 imageBook[data.fieldByName('id')]  = Ti.UI.createImageView({
image:  data.fieldByName('id')+'.png',
width:85, 
height:140
});


imageBook[data.fieldByName('id')].addEventListener('click', function(event){
 winBook.open();
   content = data.fieldByName('content');   
});


 data.next();
}
```

The error im getting

```
[ERROR] :  TiResultSet: (KrollRuntimeThread) [131428,163249] Exception getting value for column 3: Index 4 requested, with a size of 4
[ERROR] :  TiResultSet: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 requested, with a size of 4
[ERROR] :  TiResultSet:     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
[ERROR] :  TiResultSet:     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
[ERROR] :  TiResultSet:     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getType(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:130)
[ERROR] :  TiResultSet:     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.isFloat(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:125)
[ERROR] :  TiResultSet:     at ti.modules.titanium.database.TiResultSetProxy.internalGetField(TiResultSetProxy.java:109)
[ERROR] :  TiResultSet:     at ti.modules.titanium.database.TiResultSetProxy.internalGetFieldByName(TiResultSetProxy.java:205)
[ERROR] :  TiResultSet:     at ti.modules.titanium.database.TiResultSetProxy.internalGetFieldByName(TiResultSetProxy.java:195)
[ERROR] :  TiResultSet:     at ti.modules.titanium.database.TiResultSetProxy.fieldByName(TiResultSetProxy.java:169)
[ERROR] :  TiResultSet:     at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.nativeFireEvent(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  TiResultSet:     at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.fireEvent(V8Object.java:64)
[ERROR] :  TiResultSet:     at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.doFireEvent(KrollProxy.java:884)
[ERROR] :  TiResultSet:     at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.handleMessage(KrollProxy.java:1107)
[ERROR] :  TiResultSet:     at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleMessage(TiViewProxy.java:327)
[ERROR] :  TiResultSet:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
[ERROR] :  TiResultSet:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
[ERROR] :  TiResultSet:     at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:112)
[WARN] :   W/System.err: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 requested, with a size of 4
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getType(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:130)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.isFloat(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:125)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at ti.modules.titanium.database.TiResultSetProxy.internalGetField(TiResultSetProxy.java:109)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at ti.modules.titanium.database.TiResultSetProxy.internalGetFieldByName(TiResultSetProxy.java:205)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at ti.modules.titanium.database.TiResultSetProxy.internalGetFieldByName(TiResultSetProxy.java:195)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at ti.modules.titanium.database.TiResultSetProxy.fieldByName(TiResultSetProxy.java:169)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.nativeFireEvent(Native Method)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.fireEvent(V8Object.java:64)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.doFireEvent(KrollProxy.java:884)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.handleMessage(KrollProxy.java:1107)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.titanium.proxy.TiViewProxy.handleMessage(TiViewProxy.java:327)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
[WARN] :   W/System.err:    at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:112)
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [124,163373] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,163373] - In app.js:768,21
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,163373] - Message: Uncaught Error: Index 4 requested, with a size of 4
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,163374] - Source:         content = data.fieldByName('content');
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at app.js:768: Uncaught Error: Index 4 requested, with a size of 4
```

edit: I know why the error occurs. The eventlistener calls the current "Data.fieldByName('content');" when the eventlistener is clicked, with the data.next(), it will try to retrieve a column that doesnt exist. Any idea how to work around this or make the "Data.fieldByName('content');" value static in the event listener once it is created?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the method next (at the end of the while the row not exist), so when you click on the image view, it try catch the row, but really there is not row.

Try create Objects:.

```
var bookClicked = function bookClicked (c) {
    // c => content of each image view
    winBook.open();
};

while(data.isValidRow()){
    var id = data.fieldByName('id');
    var content = data.fieldByName('content');        
    imageBook[id] = {
       "content" : content,
       "view" : Ti.UI.createImageView({
           image: data.fieldByName('id')+'.png',
           width: 85, 
           height: 140
       })
    };
    imageBook[id].view.addEventListener('click', bookClicked(imageBook[id].content));
    data.next();
}
```